# Android-Sometimes app hangs with Black screen saying Channel is unrecoverably broken

Tags: android

I designed an app to plot `LatLng` `Markers` on `Google Map V2`. I stored the the LatLng values in `SQLite Database`. It's all working well. But some times when I switch between other apps and resume my app the Screen appears black and back and soft key doesn't work. I have to restart in-order to open the app again.
I monitored my phone in stacktrace but I can't understand the problem. I've posted my Stacktrace here.Please help me.

**My Stack trace is**

```
10-07 11:52:20.126    1216-1316/? E/﹕ no predefined limited group find for com.realtech.latlngrecorder, add to foreground group
10-07 11:52:20.976      933-946/? I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{43296ca0 u0 com.realtech.latlngrecorder/.LocationsList t55} time:77643091
10-07 11:52:33.376  15866-15876/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool﹕ A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.realtech.latlngrecorder/databases/latLngDB' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
10-07 11:52:33.376  15866-15876/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool﹕ A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.realtech.latlngrecorder/databases/latLngDB' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
10-07 11:54:12.986    1216-1216/? D/WhetstoneStrategy﹕ kill process in { PackageName :com.realtech.latlngrecorder Pid: 15866 Start by: activity Score:10 Old score:50 state:128 mBackgroundTimeInMillis:1444199053000 WakelockCount:0 wakelogsize:0  ActivityDestroied:false Activity size: 2 PackageInfo:{WhetstonePackageInfo#PacakgeName:com.realtech.latlngrecorderFlag:5312 [,TRIMHEAPS,SOFT_RESET,ZRAM,FLAG_DEAL_SCHEDULE] Type:0[] } tasknum:59}
10-07 11:54:12.996     933-1491/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 15866:com.realtech.latlngrecorder/u0a110 (adj 7): kill background
10-07 11:54:13.126     933-1173/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{4279e108 u0 com.realtech.latlngrecorder/com.realtech.latlngrecorder.MainPage}
10-07 11:54:13.146      933-977/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '43aa65d0 com.realtech.latlngrecorder/com.realtech.latlngrecorder.LocationsList (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
10-07 11:54:13.146      933-977/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '43aa65d0 com.realtech.latlngrecorder/com.realtech.latlngrecorder.LocationsList (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
10-07 11:54:13.146     933-1491/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '43aa65d0 com.realtech.latlngrecorder/com.realtech.latlngrecorder.LocationsList (server)'
10-07 11:54:13.146     933-1491/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{43aa65d0 u0 com.realtech.latlngrecorder/com.realtech.latlngrecorder.LocationsList}
10-07 11:54:13.176      933-948/? W/LocationManagerService﹕ RemoteException calling onLocationChanged on Reciever[43426f90 listener UpdateRecord[gps com.realtech.latlngrecorder(10110) Request[ACCURACY_FINE gps requested=0 fastest=0]]]
10-07 11:54:13.176      933-948/? W/LocationManagerService﹕ RemoteException calling onLocationChanged on Reciever[438453b0 listener UpdateRecord[gps com.realtech.latlngrecorder(10110) Request[ACCURACY_FINE gps requested=0 fastest=0]]]
10-07 11:54:34.136     933-1215/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.realtech.latlngrecorder for activity com.realtech.latlngrecorder/.LocationsList: pid=12918 uid=10110 gids={50110, 3003, 1028, 1015}
10-07 11:54:34.296    1216-1316/? E/﹕ no predefined limited group find for com.realtech.latlngrecorder, add to foreground group
10-07 11:54:34.446  12918-12918/? D/ActivityThread﹕ handleBindApplication:com.realtech.latlngrecorder
10-07 11:54:35.136    1015-1015/? D/PhoneStatusBar﹕ addNotification pkg=com.realtech.latlngrecorder;basepkg=com.android.systemui;id=252119
10-07 11:54:44.466      933-946/? E/WindowManager﹕ Starting window AppWindowToken{43695b28 token=Token{43296e00 ActivityRecord{43296ca0 u0 com.realtech.latlngrecorder/.LocationsList t55}}} timed out
10-07 11:54:54.046      933-947/? E/ActivityManager﹕ ANR in com.realtech.latlngrecorder (com.realtech.latlngrecorder/.LocationsList)
PID: 12918
Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.)
Parent: com.ttxapps.dropsync/com.ttxapps.syncapp.MainActivity
    Load: 5.33 / 4.76 / 4.41
CPU usage from 5618ms to 0ms ago:
99% 12918/com.realtech.latlngrecorder: 98% user + 1% kernel / faults: 2799 minor
1.7% 933/system_server: 0.7% user + 1% kernel / faults: 368 minor 4 major
0.7% 12640/com.ttxapps.dropsync: 0.5% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 17 minor
0.3% 1015/com.android.systemui: 0.3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
    0.3% 1175/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 7 minor 1 major
0.3% 1892/com.lbe.security.miui: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 6 minor 1 major
0% 1//init: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 92 minor
0.1% 132/irq/327-ft5x06_: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
0% 138/cfinteractive: 0% user + 0% kernel
0% 143/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
0% 1133/com.xiaomi.xmsf: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 10 minor
0.1% 9027/kworker/0:5: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
0% 12423/kworker/1:4: 0% user + 0% kernel
52% TOTAL: 50% user + 1.5% kernel + 0.1% iowait
CPU usage from 2667ms to 3183ms later with 98% awake:
98% 12918/com.realtech.latlngrecorder: 98% user + 0% kernel / faults: 245 minor
100% 12918/.latlngrecorder: 100% user + 0% kernel
3.8% 933/system_server: 1.9% user + 1.9% kernel
3.8% 947/ActivityManager: 1.9% user + 1.9% kernel
1.4% 12452/com.google.android.gms: 1.4% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3 minor
1.4% 12760/Chrome_IOThread: 1.4% user + 0% kernel
5.2% TOTAL: 0% user + 0% kernel + 5.1% iowait
10-07 11:54:57.796      933-947/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{43296ca0 u0 com.realtech.latlngrecorder/.LocationsList t55}
10-07 11:55:01.596    1216-1316/? E/﹕ no predefined limited group find for com.realtech.latlngrecorder, add to foreground group
10-07 11:55:06.186      933-947/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{43296ca0 u0 com.realtech.latlngrecorder/.LocationsList t55}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to point where your mistake/problem is, cause you didnt share your code, but I think the issue is that you do not close connection to your DB and after time it gets to the point where it uses all phone resources and therefore crashes. Look through your code to see where your memory leak is.